# How to check whether specific software is installed or not using javascript in client system?

Tags: javascript, angular, windows, typescript, operating-system

Is it possible to detect, whether client system has specific windows application installed or not using Javascript?

I developed one website, which would have to detect the application, which was developed by us only. But I want to let you know, the website name and windows application names are different. I mean consider my web application name is `X` and windows application name is `Y` not like same as `Skype webapplication` and `Skype windows application`

Consider Skype, it has web application as well as windows application. As same as Skype doing the detection for windows application installation, can I also detect the software installed or not using Javascript.

I've gone through some **StackOverflow** questions

[Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system)

[Check if the application is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211192/check-if-the-application-is-already-installed)

and some online articles

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/getinstalledrelatedapps

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/392194/How-can-I-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-clien

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1ae2d1f8-ac4a-4905-8bfd-705218b864e2/check-installed-application-using-javascript?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

and like below code

```
navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps().then(relatedApps => {
  for (let app of relatedApps) {
    console.log(app.platform);
    console.log(app.url);
    console.log(app.id);
  }
});
```

And want to let you know, I am using **Angular 5**

Comment: Simple answer - no.

Comment: Try look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Comment: @Archer Thank you for your answer ;-). Instead of javascript can I use any other programming languages to detect. Consider `google maps`, when we open our application, it will ask for `This website is trying to access your current location`, in this way can we do like `This website is tyring to access your system installed softwares`

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your response, but that will detect the client's software not the installed softwares

Comment: Not if you want to do it in a browser.  They don't have that level of access to the operating system, or browsers would be potentially the most dangerous piece of software available!

Comment: @Archer `browsers would be potentially the most dangerous piece of software available!` Yeah that's correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `getInstalledRelatedApps()` you can [check if your Windows UWP app is installed](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/#check-windows) on the users computer.

1. Update your Windows UWP app to tell it about your website, which involves updating the `Package.appxmanifest` file.

```xml
<Applications>
  <Application Id="App" ... >
      ...
      <Extensions>
         <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appUriHandler">
          <uap3:AppUriHandler>
            <uap3:Host Name="example.com" />
          </uap3:AppUriHandler>
        </uap3:Extension>
      </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
```

2. Update your website to tell it about your Windows UWP app by adding a `windows-app-web-link` file to your `/.well-known/` directory on your web server.

```json
[{
  "packageFamilyName": "MyApp_9jmtgj1pbbz6e",
  "paths": [ "*" ]
}]
```

3. Update your web app manifest on your website with details of the Windows UWP app.

```json
{
  "related_applications": [{
    "platform": "windows",
    "id": "MyApp_9jmtgj1pbbz6e!App",
  }]
}
```

3. Call `getInstalledRelatedApps()` to check if your UWP app is installed:

```js
const relatedApps = await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();
relatedApps.forEach((app) => {
  console.log(app.id, app.platform, app.url);
});
```